# Calling a function bypassing eval()

Tags: javascript, eval

I am working with a Javascript code that uses eval function.

```
eval(myString)
```

The value of myString = myFunc(arg), I want to call myFunc directly without using eval.

I dont have any control over the function to call as I am getting that function as a String (here myString). 
The arguments to that function is also part of the same string.

So, is there any way through which I can call the intended function without using eval?

Comment: Why don't you want to use eval?  Evaluating a string as Javascript is specifically what eval is for.

Comment: I dont think there's any other way

Comment: But I don't have any control over the input string. So the supplier of the string can send a malicious string and eval will execute that, hence I want to remove the eval function.

Comment: I think you might need to give us more context here.

Comment: You're concerned about the security risks of `eval`, but you're trying to run code supplied from somewhere else - that's where the risk is, not in the particular mechanism you use.  If you're accepting and executing arbitrary code, you're taking a risk, period.

Comment: Where `myString`? What is the original task that requires you to implement it in such an ugly way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit skeptical of allowing users to provide function names at all, but... Assume you have the function name in a variable and the value of arg in a variable. Boom:

```
var myString = window[fn](arg);
```

`arg` is already presumably in an argument, so that's simple enough. The next part is exatracting the function name. Just a bit of regex:

```
var fn = /^([a-z0-9_]+)\(arg\)$/i.exec(str)[1];
if (fn && typeof window[fn] === 'function') {
  window[fn](arg);
}
```

This does of course assume that the function is always in the global scope, but if it's not, you should be able to adjust accordingly for that. Also, my regex is just the first thing I came up with. It probably doesn't cover all possible function names.

If you wanted to limit the string to just a certain set of functions (and you almost certainly should), that becomes quite easy as well once you have the function name:

```
var allowedFunctions = {fn1: fn1, fn2: fn2, someOtherFunction: function() {} },
    fn = /^([a-z0-9_]+)\(arg\)$/i.exec(str)[1];

if (fn && allowedFunctions[fn]) {
    allowedFunctions[fn](arg);
} else {
    // Hah, nice try.
}
```

(If `arg` isn't actually a variable name but is some kind of literal or perhaps an arbitrary expression, this gets a little more complicated and a lot less safe.)

Comment: it seems that if the code passed the above RegExp, then using eval() to grab the function itself would not be risky, and could reach non-global closures that window.fnName cannot. in short, eval() in that case would only be able to point to one of your pre-existing functions, it would not execute arbitrary code.

Comment: @dandavis That's true. I suppose once the format has been validated, `eval` is relatively safe. It's easier to white list functions based on an object than a regex though, and as far as I'm aware, provided the eval is just `f(a)`, it's equivalent to calling `window[fn](a)` programmatically in terms of available scopes.

Comment: if it's a direct eval(), then it has access to the surrounding function's scope, like the non-window callback parameters of an AMD loader for example. if you use an indirect eval, then yes, it's globals-only

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not provide any way of calling a function represented as a string, other than using [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval). There's nothing wrong about using it, though. Given that you have no other option.

Comment: "There's nothing wrong about using it, though. Given that you have no other option." --- I will remember this justification. Seems to be universal for every case.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you may try using `Function`:

```
var sure = function(s) {
  return confirm(s);
};
var str = 'sure("Are you sure?")';
var rtn = new Function('return ' + str)();
alert(rtn);
```

Comment: I am getting: unexpected string literal 'return' expected a parameter or a ')' in parameter list